# How to ignore non virtual methods while doing mock in unit testing in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, xunit

*In my project I want to test logic of service so that's why I have mocked repository methods (DB calls) which have used in my services.*
But there are some methods has been called in my services. Those methods are not virtual methods and not even called in the interface.

As per my knowledge in unit testing, we can mock only virtual methods. So what can I do here?

Example:
In my service below code is there:

```
 ErrorDataCaptureProcess errorDataCaptureProcess = new ErrorDataCaptureProcess(user.Id);
                    **errorDataCaptureProcess.UpdateErrorCaptureData();**
```

Here is the main problem because errorDataCaptureProcess is calling a method of it. Which I can't mock.

Here is my method which is calling internally which is interacting with the database which I don't' want.

```
  public void UpdateErrorCaptureData()
            {
    ErrorDataCapture.Add(Mapper.Map<ErrorDataCapture>(error));
            }
```

I am using x-unit for unit testing.

Please help me what can I do if there are any other ways of doing it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Use Microsoft Fakes or Pose https://github.com/tonerdo/pose/